# After regenerate new session id IE 8 close current session

Tags: php, session, sessionid

After some seconds, Internet Explore 8 closed the current session.

Chrome, FireFox etc. don't have a problem with this code:

```
session_start();

// UPDATE EVERY 15 MINUTES THE SESSION ID FROM USER //
if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {

    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();

} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 10) {

    session_regenerate_id(true); $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
}
```

Whats the problem with the famous Internet Explorer?

I do something wrong?

Thanks for some help!

Comment: what's the purpose of the session id regeneration?

Comment: Could you tell us the session info from the f12 in IE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `session_cache_limiter("must-revalidate");` before your `session_start()`

Comment: Yep! Thats it...! Thanks! Had to change it a little. And that has solved the problem: `session_cache_limiter("private, must-revalidate");` Thank you very much!